# Security Checklist: Structured Exception Handling

Tags: .net, security

In the [Security Checklist: .NET Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649200.aspx)

One of the items is:

> Structured exception handling is used instead of returning error codes.

To me, returning an error code and a description/message, especially to non-admins or on production, would seem far better/more secure, a way to hide the error details, than returning the full exception.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are probably **not** referring towards The Error **displayed** too the *end user*.

I think that they mean you should use such error handling **internally**.

Refers to this [portion](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Error_Handling,_Auditing_and_Logging#Error_Handling) of the OWASP. Here the difference is between using object like *exceptions* **VS** *return codes* and the like. As the guide states, using object like exceptions, means that you can cover all the cases in more reliable manner.

The question of what data to expose to the end user, would be a totally separate question. 
**Note**: 2 lines down in [Microsoft Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649200.aspx#pagck0003_exceptionmgmt).

> System or sensitive application information is not revealed. Only
>   generic error messages are returned to the end user.